# How to sort orders by a payment method in WooCommerce?

Tags: woocommerce

I want to see only those orders that are bought by BACS/PayPal? 
Can I sort orders by payment mode in admin via WooCommerce >> Order?

Comment: Take a look at this [plugin](https://gist.github.com/bekarice/41bce677437cb8f312ed77e9f226a812) allowing to filter orders by payment method

Comment: Posting here because I don't have enough points to reply to what is currently the accepted answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/57806782/9543007), but I had a client use this code on their site and it caused all sorts of unpredictable behavior in admin (WordPress 5.5+, WooCommerce 4+). Orders that we could access directly (i.e. going to http://www.example.com/wp-admin/post.php?post=12345&action=edit) would not show up in search results, and if we typed in a page number to go to that page of Orders, those items would not appear in the list. Disabling this code fixed it. Instead of using this ans

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Add the follows code snippets in your active theme's functions.php -

```
/**
 * Add payment method bulk filter for orders
 */
function add_filter_by_payment_method_orders() {
    global $typenow;
    if ( 'shop_order' === $typenow ) {
        // get all payment methods
        $gateways = WC()->payment_gateways->payment_gateways();
        ?>
        <select name="_shop_order_payment_method" id="dropdown_shop_order_payment_method">
            <option value=""><?php esc_html_e( 'All Payment Methods', 'text-domain' ); ?></option>
            <?php foreach ( $gateways as $id => $gateway ) : ?>
            <option value="<?php echo esc_attr( $id ); ?>" <?php echo esc_attr( isset( $_GET['_shop_order_payment_method'] ) ? selected( $id, $_GET['_shop_order_payment_method'], false ) : '' ); ?>>
                <?php echo esc_html( $gateway->get_method_title() ); ?>
            </option>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </select>
        <?php
    }
}
add_action( 'restrict_manage_posts', 'add_filter_by_payment_method_orders', 99 );

/**
 * Process bulk filter order for payment method
 *
 */
function add_filter_by_payment_method_orders_query( $vars ) {
    global $typenow;
    if ( 'shop_order' === $typenow && isset( $_GET['_shop_order_payment_method'] ) ) {
        $vars['meta_key']   = '_payment_method';
        $vars['meta_value'] = wc_clean( $_GET['_shop_order_payment_method'] );
    }
    return $vars;
}
add_filter( 'request', 'add_filter_by_payment_method_orders_query', 99 );
```

Comment: Great one. Thanks

Comment: A quick note, for the add_filter method I had to add one more parameter at the end of `1` in order to get the filter to display: `add_filter( 'request', 'add_filter_by_payment_method_orders_query', 99, 1 );` The last param specifies the number of args to pass to the custom function.